# como posso colocar documentos PDF em meu site usando o api do google drive

Tags: html, pdf, google-drive-api

estou querendo colocar documentos PDFs em exibição no meu site no qual o administrador cadastraria o link que está em seu Google drive e após isso o documento estaria disponível para os usuários normais verem pesquisando cheguei no seguinte código HTML:

`<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/open?id=1bMIyRuEDg_nsg8uSBu5GBF7CP7sj6wIs" width="600" height="780" style="border: none;"></iframe>`

entretanto quando coloco no host aparece apenas uma pagina em branco com meu header e footer sem aparecer os documentos

Answer (score -1):

Use a opção visualiza no documento em vez de compartilhar.

```html
<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bMIyRuEDg_nsg8uSBu5GBF7CP7sj6wIs/preview" width="600" height="780" style="border: none;">
    </iframe>
<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxrMaW3xINrsR3h2cWx0OUlwRms/preview" width="600" height="780" style="border: none;">
    </iframe>
<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B50I05L0hWhcdmw5ck9QRFhMLTQ/preview" width="600" height="780" style="border: none;">
    </iframe>
```

Comment: Só não entendi como vc conseguiu o link de visualização porque no gdrive so mostra o de compartilhar

Comment: No caso do seu documento eu peguei o identificado do arquivo '1bMIyRuEDg_nsg8uSBu5GBF7CP7sj6wIs' e adicionei /preview. No outros documentos como estão no meu google drive fiz. Botão direito e clica visualização.

Comment: não esqueça de tornar o arquivo/documento visível